# Class 'App\Libraries\QRcode' not found - using CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, qr-code, codeigniter-4

I am new to Codeigniter 4. I want to do it without composer.I have included Library using namespace and use in controller but problem still persist....

```
use App\Libraries\Ciqrcode;
public function qr_code()
    {
        $template = new Ciqrcode();

        $params['data'] = 'This is a text to encode become QR Code';
        $params['level'] = 'H';
        $params['size'] = 10;
        $params['savename'] = FCPATH.'tes.png';
        $template->generate($params);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your Question is not very clear. Your error shows different path compared to the imported path on your code shared.

Comment: It seems the library you are trying to use is missing some files

Comment: file was there but codeigniter now use namesapce and use....

Comment: I think your issue is more with your understanding of namespaces. You may have relocated the `Ciqrcode` class successfully but you haven't adjusted the namespacing of anything else that class depends on; hence the fact that your actual error is not finding `QRcode` within the `Ciqrcode` class. If you're manually relocating namespaced classes, then ALL classes have to be relocated accordingly or it will never work. FYI this is exactly what Composer helps you avoid.

Comment: @parttimeturtle Agreed.